# How nextDate takes timezone into account?

Tags: swift, date, timezone

Have following code:

```swift
let start = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2022, month: 4, day: 25).date!
let end = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2022, month: 7, day: 2).date!
let dateInterval: DateInterval = .init(start: start, end: end)

let m2030 = dateInterval.dates(matching: .init(calendar: .current, timeZone: TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Budapest"), hour: 20, minute: 30, weekday: 2))

extension DateInterval {
    func dates(matching components: DateComponents) -> [Date] {
        var start = self.start
        var dates: [Date] = []
        while let date = Calendar.current.nextDate(after: start, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .strict), date <= end {
            dates.append(date)
            start = date
        }
        return dates
    }
}
```

And I see this in console:

```
(lldb) po m2030
▿ 10 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2022-04-25 13:30:00 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 672586200.0
```

Why console says: `13:30:00 +0000` which in Budapest is `15:30`, though my request was show times Budapest time at `20:30`?

I am now abroad, does it matter? In Cambodia. :) +5 hour to Budapest.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use a custom calendar using the Budapest timezone. Try like this:

---

```
extension DateInterval {
    func dates(matching components: DateComponents, using calendar: Calendar = .current) -> [Date] {
        var start = self.start
        var dates: [Date] = []
        while let date = calendar.nextDate(after: start, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .strict), date <= end {
            dates.append(date)
            start = date
        }
        return dates
    }
}
```

---

```
var budapestCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
budapestCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Budapest")!

let start = DateComponents(calendar: budapestCalendar, year: 2022, month: 4, day: 25).date!
let end = DateComponents(calendar: budapestCalendar, year: 2022, month: 7, day: 2).date!
let dateInterval: DateInterval = .init(start: start, end: end)

let m2030 = dateInterval.dates(matching: .init(hour: 20, minute: 30, weekday: 2), using: budapestCalendar)

for date in m2030 {
    print(date)
}
```

This will print:

> 2022-04-25 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-05-02 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-05-09 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-05-16 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-05-23 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-05-30 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-06-06 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-06-13 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-06-20 18:30:00 +0000
> 2022-06-27 18:30:00 +0000